# Multiple slice in list indexing for numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Numpy array admits a list of indices, for example

```
a = np.arange(1000)
l = list([1,44,66,33,90,345])
a[l] = 22
```

But this method don't work if we want to use a multiple slice indexing or indices plus a slice, for example.

```
a = np.arange(1000)
l = list([1,44,66,33,90, slice(200,300) , slice(500,600) ])
a[l] = 22
```

This code returns an error message:

```
IndexError: too many indices
```

My question is very simple: 
do you know if in **numpy** or **scipy** there exist an efficient method for using this kind of indexing?

Or what's a good and efficient way for using an indexing method like this?

Don't forget that the usage of slices produce a very fast code; and my problem is to have as faster as possible code.

Comment: It helps to know how you loop through this. What do you know in advance and what do you know only per iteration? What other constraints are there on the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What comes to my mind:

```
a = np.arange(1000)
l = np.hstack(([1, 44, 66, 33, 90], np.arange(200, 300), np.arange(500, 600)))
a[l] = 22
```

I'm not sure if it's the simplest way, but it works.

**Edit:** you're right that this is slower than using slices; but you cannot create a slice object with arbitrary values. Maybe you should just do several assignments then:

```
%timeit a[np.hstack(([1, 44, 66, 33, 90], np.arange(200, 300), np.arange(500, 600)))] = 22
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.5 us per loop

%timeit a[[1, 44, 66, 33, 90]] = 22; a[200:300] = 22; a[500:600] = 22
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.4 us per loop
```

Comment: But this method don't uses the slices, that are very fast respect to the array indexing. It works but is not efficient.

Comment: @Giggi True; edited. I don't know if there's a way to achieve what you want, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fancy indexing to build an index list.

```
l = numpy.array([1,44,66,33,90]+range(200,300)+range(500,600))
a[l] = 22
```

But as [@Lev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13525348/709852) pointed out, this may not be any faster (though it almost certainly will be if you can precompute the index list).

However, fancy indexing applies per-axis. So you can fancy index on one axis, and slice the others, if that helps at all:

```
a = numpy.random.randn(4, 5, 6)
l = numpy.array([1, 2])
a[l, slice(None), slice(2, 4)] = 10
```