# Pythonic way of slicing out part of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose you have the following numpy array,

```
>>> x = numpy.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

and you want to extract a new numpy array consisting of only the first three (3) and last four (4) elements, i.e.,

```
>>> y = x[something]
>>> print y
[0 1 2 7 8 9 10]
```

Is this possible? I know that to extract the first three numbers you simply do `x[:3]` and to extract the last four you do `x[-4:]`, but is there a simple way of extracting all that in a simple slice? I know this can be done by, e.g., appending both calls,

```
 >>> y = numpy.append(x[:3],x[-4:])
```

but I was wondering if there is some simple little trick to do it in a more direct, pythonic way, without having to reference `x` again (i.e., I first thought that maybe `x[-4:3]` could work but I realized immediately that it didn't made sense).

Comment: The question is similar to this one, but the proposed solutions there won't work for newer numpy versions so it's probably not relevant anymore. Still might be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525266/multiple-slice-in-list-indexing-for-numpy-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use [index arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays).

```
indices = list(range(3))+list(range(-4,0))
y = x[indices]
```

You can probably drop `list` casts (not sure because python 3 changed the behaviour a bit). Or you could use `numpy` range genreators.

Edit: not sure why the downvote, cause [it works](http://ideone.com/FkVpsP):

```
import numpy
x = numpy.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
indices = list(range(3))+list(range(-4,0))
y = x[indices]
print(y)
```

Comment: Yeah, actually is the same thing that occurred to me after watching @mgilson answer (see the comments). Maybe if you add what we commented in that post regarding the use of `list` around the `range` I could accept this as the best answer :).

Comment: I was typing my answer before seeing comments, I wanted to make it with "dynamic" ranges, and link to the docs.

Answer (score 4):

A simple slice probably won't work.  You can use numpy's extended slicing:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> something = [0, 1, 2, -4, -3, -2, -1]
>>> a[something] 
array([0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Notice I passed in a list of indices that I wanted to take from the original array ...

Frankly though, your solution with `np.append` is likely just as good...

Comment: It could seem like the same, but now that I see your example, I think that an elegant way of doing the same could be: `something = range(0,3) + range(-4,0,1)`. So a general way of slicing the first `n` elements and the last `m` elements would be: `something = range(0,n) + range(-m,0,1)`!

Comment: Be careful with adding `range` together, in Python 3 they're `range` objects, not lists, and so you'll get a TypeError.

Comment: Hi @Ffisegydd; thanks for the input. This means that a more version independant way of doing this would be `something = list(range(0,n)) + list(range(-m,0,1))`?

Comment: Yeah that should be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

```
np.arange(11)[np.r_[0:3,7:11]]
# array([ 0,  1,  2,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

`np.r_` is a function, actually an indexable object, in `numpy/lib/index_tricks`.  It takes multiple slices, or indexes, and concatenates them into one indexing array.

```
np.r_[0:3,7:11]
# array([ 0,  1,  2,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

Or borrowing from `luk32`s answer, a negative slice works:

```
a[np.r_[:3,-4:0]]
```

An alternative to splicing the 2 parts is to delete the middle.  `s_` lets you use slice notation inside the function.

```
np.delete(np.arange(11),np.s_[3:7])
# array([ 0,  1,  2,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

Look at the code for the `.lib.index_tricks`, `delete`, and `insert` functions for more ideas on how to construct index arrays from multiple pieces.

Sometimes a boolean index is convenient.  Make it all True or False, and flip selected elements.

```
i = np.ones(a.shape,dtype='bool')
i[3:7] = False
a[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

These days one can use the built-in function [`np.setdiff1d()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) like so:

```py
import numpy as np


x = np.asarray([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
x_cut_out = np.asarray([3, 4, 5, 6])

x_new = np.setdiff1d(
    ar1=x,
    ar2=x_cut_out
)
```

This returns the unique values in `x` that are not in `x_cut_out`.

```
>>> print(x_new)
[ 0  1  2  7  8  9 10]
```