# Using : for multiple slicing in list or numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, slice

I'm having some difficulty trying to figure out how to do extract multiple values in a list that are spaced some indices apart. For example, given a list `l = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, I want to only extract the values `[1,2,3] and [6,7,8,9]`. I could do `l[1:4]+l[6:-1]`, but is there a way such to write `l[1:4,6:-1]`?

This is really a ghost problem to the actual problem I am having in a pandas dataframe. I have a dataframe, `df`, with columns `['A','B','C','I1','D','E','F','I2','I3']`, and I only want to keep the important columns `['I1', 'I2', 'I3']`. Now, the current approach I am doing is

`df.drop(df.columns[0:3], axis=1, inplace=True)` 
`df.drop(df.columns[4:7], axis=1, inplace=True)`

Is there a way to do it such that we can do it in 1 line without writing the column values out explicitly?

Thank you!
PS. I know pandas dataframes use numpy, and I haven't found any workarounds in numpy either,  but I think the syntax to drop columns is of the standard python list format, if that makes any sense.

**EDIT:** I found a way to do it for numpy but it is also 2 lines, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525266/multiple-slice-in-list-indexing-for-numpy-array). We can do: 
 
`indices = np.hstack((np.arange(0:3), np.arange(4:7))`
`df.drop(df.columns[indices], axis=1, inplace=True)`

However, I'm still looking for 1-line generalized methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for concanecate indices:

```
print (np.r_[1:4, 6:10])
[1 2 3 6 7 8 9]
```

Comment: Ah I see! Wow, index_tricks is full of stuff. So this can only work with numpy arrays? Built in python doesn't have anything like this?

Comment: Hi, the numpy.r_ function doesn't work with `[1:4, 6:-1`], because it doesn't have any numpy array to refer to. This means we have to use `[1:4, 6:array.shape[0]-1]`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Another possible solution is  `[1:4, 6:len(array)-1]`

Comment: `r_` expands the slices into an array of indices. Such an array can't be used to index lists, at least not without a loop or comprehension.

Comment: Yes, but then you can use `iloc` for selecting.

Comment: @hpaulj - anf if need remove columns then works perfect `df.drop(df.columns[np.r_[1:2, 3:len(df.columns)-1]], axis=1, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension, you can do:

```
>>> [item for item in l[1:4] + l[6:-1]]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

You can also use `extend()` like this:

```
>>> res = l[1:4]
>>> res.extend(l[6:-1])
>>> res
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```