# Select 2 ranges of columns to load - read_csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading in an excel .csv file using pandas.read_csv(). I want to read in 2 separate column ranges of the excel spreadsheet, e.g. columns A:D AND H:J, to appear in the final DataFrame. I know I can do it once the file has been loaded in using indexing, but can I specify 2 ranges of columns to load in?

I've tried something like this....

```
usecols=[0:3,7:9]
```

I know I could list each column number induvidually e.g.

```
usecols=[0,1,2,3,7,8,9]
```

but I have simplified the file in question, in my real file I have a large number of rows so I need to be able to select 2 large ranges to read in...

Comment: check function [numpy.r_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40970268/2901002)

Comment: @jezrael thanks for that, have added as an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's an official-pretty-pandaic-way to do it with pandas.

But, You can do it this way:

```
# say you want to extract 2 ranges of columns
# columns 5 to 14 
# and columns 30 to 66

import pandas as pd

range1 = [i for i in range(5,15)]
range2 = [i for i in range(30,67)]
usecols = range1 + range2

file_name = 'path/to/csv/file.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(file_name, usecols=usecols)
```

Comment: You don't need a list comprehension. Just use `usecols = list(range(5,15)) + list(range(30,67))`

Answer (score 4):

As @jezrael notes you can use [numpy.r](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40970268/2901002%20so%20with%20the%20op%20example) to do this in a more pythonic and legible way

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file_name = 'path/to/csv/file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, usecols=np.r_[0:3, 7:9])
```

**Gotchas**
Watch out when use in combination with `names` that you have allowed for the extra column pandas adds for the index ie. For csv columns 1,2,3 (3 items) `np.r_` needs to be `0:3` (4 items)